# Is there a better way to handle result logic in Sprite Kit? (Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to handle result of the Game. But I am not sure of that the following is the correct way or not. The method is working, I am looking for a better solution to calculate the result.

```
func result(a: Int, b: Int, z: Int){
    // a: User/Opponent'answer (Int), b: User/Opponent'answer (Int), z: Correct Answer
    let az = abs(a - z)  //User/Opponent based on GameData.shared.userDetected
    let bz = abs(b - z)  //Opponent/User based on GameData.shared.userDetected

    if GameData.shared.userDedected == true {


        if az == bz {
            print("Draw")

        } else if az < bz {
            print("User won az < az")

        } else if bz < az {
            print("User lost bz < az")

        }
    } else if GameData.shared.userDedected == false {
        if az == bz {
            print("Draw")

        } else if az < bz {
            print("User Lost az < bz")

        } else if bz < az {
            print("User won bz < az")

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but if you want to clean it up some, you can do:

```
func result(a: Int, b: Int, z: Int){
    // a: User/Opponent'answer (Int), b: User/Opponent'answer (Int), z: Correct Answer
    let az = abs(a - z) * GameData.shared.userDedected ? 1 : -1  //User/Opponent based on GameData.shared.userDetected
    let bz = abs(b - z) * GameData.shared.userDedected ? 1 : -1  //Opponent/User based on GameData.shared.userDetected

    if az == bz {
        print("Draw")
    } else if az < bz {
        print("User won az < bz")
    } else if bz < az {
        print("User lost bz < az")
    }
}
```

Basically, based on value of userDedected determines if the sign should be flipped

you could also do:

```
func result(a: Int, b: Int, z: Int){
        // a: User/Opponent'answer (Int), b: User/Opponent'answer (Int), z: Correct Answer
        let value = (abs(a - z)  - abs(b - z) ) * GameData.shared.userDedected ? 1 : -1  //User/Opponent based on GameData.shared.userDetected

        if value == 0 {
            print("Draw")
        } else if value < 0 {
            print("User won az < bz")
        } else if value > 0 {
            print("User lost bz < az")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you like it, I didn't check it on the compilator:

```
func result(a: Int, b: Int, z: Int) -> Bool {
    let az = abs(a - z)  //User/Opponent based on GameData.shared.userDetected
    let bz = abs(b - z)  //Opponent/User based on GameData.shared.userDetected

    let userWon:Bool = (az < bz && GameData.shared.userDedected == true) || (az > bz && GameData.shared.userDedected == false) ? true:false

    if az == bz {
        print("Draw")
        return true
    }

    if userWon == true {
        print("Won")
        return true
    }
    else {
        print("Lost")
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: your ternary operiation is not needed,  you are already returning a true false value (it comes out to `true ? true : false` or `false ? true : false`  You can even eliminate the == true and == false, and instead just do !GameData.shared.userDedected to get false

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I don't know what he wanna do, I opened two ways, he can choose the best way for him

Comment: I was just letting you know you have redundancy with your let userWon,  basically it can be simplified to `let userWon:Bool = (az < bz && GameData.shared.userDedected) || (az > bz && !GameData.shared.userDedected)`